# Android - How to close a given number of Activities from the stack?

Tags: android, android-activity

Android - How to close a given number of Activities from the stack?

I'm making an app where all the activities
display webviews.
So, I just have one activity called BaseActivity.
Every time a new screen needs to be pushed, I just 
push an instance of BaseActivity with a different webview.

Let's say this is my stack of activities:

```
-A1
-A2
-A3
-A4
-A5
-A6
```

Being on the A6 activity, the app should clear the activities
stack untill the A3 activity when I call a method.

How could I do that on Android?

I can't use startActivityForResult neither FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

In BlackBerry, when I want to do something like that, I use to call a method
like this:

```
public static void closeScreens(int screenCount) {
        for (int i = 0; i < screenCount; i++) {
            Screen screen = UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen();
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(screen);
        }
    }
```

Maybe, there is an equivalent in Android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use -  public void finishActivity (int requestCode). Doc says,

Force finish another activity that you had previously started with startActivityForResult(Intent, int requestCode).

Comment: thanks but as mentioned in the question, I just can't use startActivityForResult

Comment: why can't you use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP?

Comment: can't use it because I have to do this: Intent a = new Intent(this,A.class); a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); startActivity(a); but all my activities derive from BaseActivity and this line Intent a = new Intent(this,A.class); receives an unique type of Activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, SplashScreenActivity.class);
mIntent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startNewActivity(YourActivity.this, mIntent );
```

Comment: thanks but I can't use that since I just have a single Activity type: BaseActivity

Comment: SplashScreenActivity is the name of the class, not the type

Comment: @MattTaylor, I don't think this is going to work since I should do this: Intent mIntent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, BaseActivity.class);

Comment: @Boel you're misunderstanding this code. For example, I have the class: public class MyMainActivity extends ActionBarActivity, and I'm trying to navigate to: public class MySecondActivity extends BaseActivity. I would use Intent mIntent = new Intent(MyMainActivity .this, MySecondActivity .class);, not reference the base type